# How to use maryTTS in Java (VSCode)?

Tags: java, javafx, text-to-speech

I want to use MaryTTS, but in my project, i don't know how to add libs contain file .jar.
I have dowloaded jars and put them in my pom file, them are incorrect.
HELP MEEE, PLEASE !!

The way add libs have jars in pom file and how to run them.

Comment: You are using Maven.  You don't need to download jars, Maven does that for you.  I suggest you study a [Maven tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/maven), then the [documentation for the software you want to use](https://github.com/marytts/marytts#maven).

Answer (score 0):

Rollback everything you have done until now and add this to your `pom.xml` into the `<dependencies>` tag:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.dfki.mary/marytts -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.dfki.mary</groupId>
    <artifactId>marytts</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```